# sending data to Server is not working

Tags: android, client-server

I am a beginner in Android. I have developed a application that will send location information to server(**latitude** and **longitude** value).

I am using `Dynamic IP` as for now for sending information.

Problem which I face is while using `WIFI` the **information is passed to the server** but when I use my `Mobile Internet` I am **unable to send the information to the server**. Please help.

```
 Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation( LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);      
    if (location != null) 
    {
    String message = String.format( "Current Location \n Longitude: %1$s \n Latitude:     %2$s  ",location.getLongitude(), location.getLatitude());
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, message,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.1.7/YourPhpScript1.php");

    try {

       List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
       nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", "12345"));
       nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("message", message));
       httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
       httpclient.execute(httppost);

     }
 catch (ClientProtocolException e)
    {

} 
 catch (IOException e)
   {

   }`
```

Here 192.168.1.7 is my dynamic IP address

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its about port redirection problem,

This ip address "192.168.1.7" is you local ip address. Which is just reachable via WIFI but when you use your mobile internet you are not in your local network.You should connect via your external ip address. But your modem probably block all your connection. Redirect port 80 from your modem to your computer and disable your computer's firewall port 80.

**Just check all these step by step.**

1. Open port 80 from you pc's firewall (http://windows.microsoft.com/is-IS/windows-vista/Open-a-port-in-Windows-Firewall)
2. Redirect port 80 from your modem to your PC (Find your modem brand from list http://portforward.com/english/routers/port_forwarding/
3. Change your application to connect from your external ip address. "http://external ip address/YourPhpScript1.php" (To find your external ip address visit http://www.whatismyip.com/)

**Your current infrastructure**

```
  +-----+         +-------+                                     +---+
  | PC  | --------| Modem |-------- INTERNET  ~  ~   ~   ~   ~  |   |
  |     |      |  +-------+                                     |   |
  +-----+      | (external IP 75.1xx.2x.3x)                     +---+
(192.168.1.7)  | (internal IP 192.168.1.1)               (With mobile internet)
               |
            +---+
            |   |
            |   |
            +---+
         Mobile Phone (With wifi connection)
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to communicate to server from an android application. I am assuming that you are trying to use raw sockets for that.

My suggestion is, you should use json/soap communication. It is very simple and you should be able to go through firewalls and other communication barriers when you use it as it uses the standard http port 80.

To make it secure, you can use https( port 443).

Apart from that, the problem here appears to be more of network then of android programming. Can you please post some of your code so I can give some comments on it.

Comment: I am using http get and post method to send data to server

Comment: Please also post the server url of your application.

Comment: May be you have not given internet permission in the menifest file, double check the application permissions.

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"></uses-permission> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
<user-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"></user-permission> These are the permissions in my Manifest file

Comment: Hum.., now I can see the code. Are you running the same code while trying your application from mobile internet ?, if so, it is not going to work as the IP address 192.168.1.7 will not work from mobile internet as it is your local address. The reason it is working from wifi is, it does not require internet, it is rather operating in intranet.

Comment: Nope, unless it is a class A IP (Public IP), i.e. IP accessible from anywhere on the internet. I would recommend you to buy a cheap hosting plan and upload your web code there. Use URL instead of IP for accessing the page. It will surely work from anywhere.

Comment: @BSO If you want to use the server running in your local network for testing, you will also need to configure port forwarding on your WiFI router (I guess you use one), so the connection coming to your public IP from the outside is forwarded to your server running on 192.168.1.7.